# Datetimepicker: Customizing css

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

For picking a date and time I use a datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetime-picker).
The widget allows showing date and time "[side-by-side](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#sidebyside)".
It all works great and picking is no problem.
But, the time part of the widget uses arrows to increment/decrement hours and minutes. These arrow buttons are hidden and only show when you hover over the area the arrow button is.
I tried to search the CSS for the "hover" setting, so I can change the behavior of it. I want it to show all the time, not only if hovered over.

Any ideas where and how to change these settings?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an online demo, a codepen of it or something where we can see what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

> .timepicker .glyphicon-chevron-**up**{    background-color: #eee; }

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [that DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/),
inspect the code of page, in console type

```
var picker = $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget');
$(picker).appendTo('body')
```

Explore the code of datetime picker element at the bottom of the page